# No download button for redemption codes for custom app in Apple Business Manager

Tags: apple-business

I've managed to release my app through apple business manager but when generating redemption codes there is no download button showing so I'm unable to get my redemption codes.

[image]

Is there a certain time before the download button appears?

Answer (score 0):

For the download button to be activated, you must enter the number of licenses you want to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the redemption side of things (ABM) instead of the generation side - which is App Store Connect.

- https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/offer-promo-codes/request-and-manage-promo-codes/

[image]